# Check if a field exists in JsonObject using gson in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a following JSON structure

```
{
  "entity": {
    "bsid": "8452",
    "name": "Name limited",
    "contact": "CONTACT",
    "imgurl": "http://testlocalhost.com/",
  },
  "doc": {
    "details": {
      "bsid": "8452",
      "type": "pdf"
    }
    "name": "estimates",
  }
}
```

I need to find if ***bsid*** is present in the JSON structure. An important point to note is that the structure may change. However, what is guaranteed is ***bsid*** field will be present somewhere in the structure which I need to find and if present, get its value(8452 in this case. The value will be same everywhere it's present)

Since I am using google gson library, I know this can be achieved with the following statement:

```
jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("entity").get("bsid")
```

Here jsonObject is actually JsonObject of google gson which holds the above structure

However, as I mentioned the structure may change and ***bsid*** may not be present directly under ***entity***. Hence I need a way to find a field in the structure globally.

Comment: Can it be absolutely anywhere? Like nested in an arbitrary number of objects deep?

Comment: Yes @lchristmann absolutely anywhere in the whole structure as the structure is ever changing

Comment: You'll probably have to recursively go through the JSON object and look for a `bsid` key [as shown in this tutorial where a whole JSON object is recursively printed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t129R2FvITw&t=1s&ab_channel=TylerCaraza-Harter). I'm not aware of any function in the `Gson` library that would make this job easier. (sth like a global search option for keys). Thinking outside the box, you could however execute a regex on the still serialized string. That would be the most efficient solution that comes to mind right now.

Comment: you should fix your JSON structure and give the bsid a fixed place, where you can reliable find it.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to walk the json and find the value.

```
@Test
void jsonTest() {
    String json = """
{
    "entity": {
        "name": "Name limited",
        "contact": "CONTACT",
        "imgurl": "http://testlocalhost.com/"
    },
    "doc": {
        "details": {
            "type": "pdf",
            "test": [
                "bar",
                { "testing": "ok" },
                {
                    "foo": false,
                    "bsid": "12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        "name": "estimates"
    }
}
""";
    findValue(
        JsonParser.parseString( json ).getAsJsonObject(),
        "bsid"
    )
        .findAny()
        .ifPresentOrElse(
            System.out::println,
            () -> System.out.println( "Empty" )
        );

}

private Stream<String> findValue( JsonElement json, String field ) {
    if ( json.isJsonArray() )
        return StreamSupport.stream( json.getAsJsonArray().spliterator(), false )
            .flatMap( element -> findValue( element, field ) );
    if ( ! json.isJsonObject() ) return Stream.empty();
    return json.getAsJsonObject()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap( entry -> field.equals( entry.getKey() ) ?
            Stream.of( entry.getValue().getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString() ) :
            findValue( entry.getValue(), field  )
        );
}
```

Comment: This is not giving correct results when the structure gets complex

Comment: I assume it's because it's not parsing JsonArrays